# What is institutional open access fees?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

There is such a paragraph in the conference introduction that I want to submit. What does institutional open access fees refer to here? Thank you!

> ACM uses the corresponding author during the publication process for
> accepted submissions. For example, institutional open access fees will
> be charged to the corresponding author’s institution.

Comment: Probably the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_processing_charge